# issue on making requests through proxy when using "sudo" command

Tags: proxy, centos, sudo

Having problems when using the "sudo" command to make requests through a proxy server:

If i don't use sudo, the request goes through the proxy `10.139.212.25:8080`

```
wget http://www.proxypronto com/

Connecting to 10.139.212.25:8080... connected.

Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden (Blocked by Trustwave Secure Web Gateway)

2015-12-01 13:11:47 ERROR 403: Forbidden (Blocked by Trustwave Secure Web Gateway).
```

If I use sudo, the request does not go through the proxy `10.139.212.25:8080`

```
sudo wget http://www.proxypronto com/

Resolving www.proxypronto com ... 96.31.64.186

Connecting to www.proxypronto com |96.31.64.186|:80... failed: Connection refused.
```

How can I make the requests to go through the proxy when using "sudo"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, try the following comand:

```
sudo http_proxy=$http_proxy wget "http://stackoverflow.com"
```

At first glance, you need to add enviroment variables to sudoers config:

```
 sudo visudo
```

add these lines

```
Defaults env_keep += "ftp_proxy http_proxy https_proxy no_proxy"
```

or, use separate lines:

```
Defaults  env_keep +="http_proxy"
Defaults  env_keep +="https_proxy"
Defaults  env_keep +="HTTP_PROXY"
Defaults  env_keep +="HTTPS_PROXY"
```